# How to do multilable classification by hand?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, mahout, document-classification

I have a huge data set and would like to do a multi-lable classification where each object can be assigned to more than one class. I'm using a Naive Bayer Classifier in Apache Mahout to do that. However it is not designed for multi-lable classification and just assign class with highest probability to each object. How can I extend this classifier to my scenario?

One solution that I was thinking was to put a threshold and assign classes whose probabilities are larger than the threshold. But it is not easy to find the threshold so it does not work. I wonder to know if any one has any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You need to train a binary classifier for each class. Train set should contain data with target class and other arbitrary data not matching the target class.